# Get callers (CURL) IP and SERVER_NAME - PHP

Tags: php, curl

Hey i have some servers who are calling my API with a curl, every caller have a API key that is registered in my database with a server name (etc. example.com) - But in somehow its returning the HOST (etc. web1.meebox.net) so i can´t validate the callings. Currently im just using:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$website = gethostbyaddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']);
```

and:

```
$ip = $_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR'];
$website = $_SERVER['REMOTE_NAME'];
```

How can i get it to tell me what ip and server name that belongs to the server and not host.

Thanks! :)

Comment: If `$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']` is returning your own server address for external calls, something is wrong. Are you running a proxy of some sort?

Comment: what do you mean 'server name'? example.com is a domain record in ns server, it may also have a lots of aliases. Curl (as any other http client) knows nothing about ns records.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not all IPs have reverse mappings. And of those reverse mappings, they may not map to the "hostname" they're coming from. E.g. DNS names can map an unlimited number of hostnames to a single IP. but a single IP can only ever be "reversed" to a single hostname.

e.g. consider a shared server:

```
www.example.com -> 192.168.1.3
www.example.net -> 192.168.1.3
www.example.org -> 192.168.1.3
etc...
etc...
etc...
```

but

```
192.168.1.3 -> server-x.hostingcompany.com
```

You cannot reliably retrieve the hostname of a remote host, because that all you have is an IP address, and IPs are not "unique" identifiers of any particular hostname.

Comment: Alright, i see. But how should it be done? Its important that the API key is bounded to one server. How can i get something unique from the server that i get can get without he can minipulate my calling file on his server to get clean access? :) Any ideas.

Comment: @Emil how about binding it to the server's IP?

Comment: Go for an iron-clad licensing agreement, rather than code-based solutions. it's php code, they can trivially disable/bypass any auth code you care to try and put onto THEIR server.

Comment: @MarcB The problem is that its a click-and-earn system im developing for some research marketing (kind of for fun). So the user have to verify that he is the owner of the API key else someone else could use it and manipulate the viewing content. Facebook are doing it with their API, it have to be possible in somehow. But how?

Comment: @Pekka웃 I though of that to, but it is not possible because it would destroy the payment system because serverals servers could be on the same shared IP.

Comment: @Emil there is likely no other way, because there are no distinguishing characteristics between a call made from site A and one made from site B on the same server.

Comment: consider that a malicious client could install your package on a million servers, all hidden behind a single NAT gateway. you'll only ever seen **ONE** IP doing requests to your api, but in the background there's those million servers violating your license. You **CANNOT** have bulletproof 100% reliable checking on this. pick a level of protect you're comfortable with and code for that.

Comment: Okay, thanks guys. Then i would go for binding it to the servers IP and work-out a licensing agreement. :-) Thanks guys!!